# How to get the common values from columns of two different tables?

Tags: sql

I have two tables `customers` table and `suppliers` table. In both the tables, I have `City` column with different city names but there may be some cities which are present in both the tables. I want to retrieve only those values (city names) which are present in both. How can I get those values?

Comment: Not sure how those 2 tables are joined, but it seems that the `WHERE` clause would at least have: `customers.city != '' AND suppliers.city != ''` ... if either city could be null, then it would be: `customers.city IS NOT NULL AND suppliers.city IS NOT NULL` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the inner join, something like this

```sql
select customers.name, customers.city, suppliers.address
from customers
inner join suppliers on customers.city = suppliers.city
```

> MySQL INNER JOIN Keyword
> The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables.

[MySQL INNER JOIN Keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT c.city from customers c iNNER JOIN  suppliers s on c.city = s.city;`  Yes this worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to `INNER JOIN` two `SELECT` statements.
Attention on the alias!

```
select distinct city from 
(select city from customers) c
inner join
(select city from suppliers) s
on c.city = s.city;
```